# Failure to catch an optional value equalling nil in conditional assignment

Tags: swift, option-type

Trying to execute an update only on a non-nil string, but the following code seems to execute the conditional clause regardless of whether the text (string optional) has a value or not.

submitText is a UITextField and this code is executing on a press of a UIButton.
tvc.addTask expects one task argument of type String.

I've tried explicit and implicit unwrapping, both to no avail.

```swift
if let str = submitText.text {
    print(str)
    tvc.addTask(task: str)
}
```

I expected the code not to execute if the textField is empty but instead it gives me a "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" fatal error. However, the string prints out correctly based on what is entered in the textbox.

Comment: *empty* is not equal to `nil`.

Comment: @vadian even so, a **String?** wouldn't become _nil_ through unwrapping and assignment to a **String**, surely it would just be _""_ ? I don't understand what's causing this error.

Comment: Have you checked that `tvc` is not `nil`?

Comment: @vadian `tvc` was `nil` . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `text` variable never equals to `nil`, it is optional only for reseting its value.

```
submitText.text = nil
```

Check like this

```
if !submitText.text.isEmpty {
    tvc.addTask(task: submitText.text!)
}
```

`tvc` equals nil.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" fatal error maybe because (as per the above code) submitText is set to nil or tvc = nil.

Make sure your textField/tvc is initialised before extracting its value.

In your code,

```
if let str = submitText.text {
        print(str)
        tvc.addTask(task: str)
    }
```

you will not get above error, if submitText.text = nil.